# Mongoose returns empty JSON array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mongoose, express, MongoDB return an empty json array -- [].

How can I fix this?

Have installed all the packages. Have entered data into MongoDB using Robo 3t, so I think the problem is that mongoose is not requesting data from MongoDB the right way.

server.js: this is in /app folder

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import Issue from './models/issue.js';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/issues');

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});

router.get("/issues", function(req, res) {
    Issue.find({})
    .exec(function (err, issues) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log("successfully requested");
            res.json(issues);
    });
});
```

Index.js: this is in /app/models folder

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const issueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    responsible: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    severity: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Open'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Issue', issueSchema, 'Issues');
```

Comment: from robo3T can check and update me on your issue collection name?

Comment: It's "Issues" Problem still not solved.

Comment: Check my answer it worked for me I ran your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `router` to `app` as shown below and make sure your collection name is `Issues` in database.
**Don't forget to restart your server**.

```
app.get("/issues", function(req, res) {
    Issue.find({})
    .exec(function (err, issues) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log("successfully requested");
            res.json(issues);
    });
});
```